Prove that $R / J$ is a field and determine $|R / J|$ with $J=(1-2 i) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i] .$
Exam question: In the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, consider the ideal
$J=(1-2 i) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i] .$
(a) Prove that $R / J$ is a field and determine $|R / J|$.
(Check: The order $|R / J|$ is a prime number; this could also be useful for proving the first statement in (a).)
Solution: The generator of $J$ has norm $|1-2 i|^2=1^2+2^2=5$, a prime number. Therefore, $1-2 i \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is irreducible (and not a unit). Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a principal ideal ring, $J$ is a maximal ideal (Theorem 1), and thus $R / J$ is a field (see Corollary 1).
From $1-2 i \in J$, it follows that $a-2 a i=a(1-2 i) \in J$ for all $a \in \mathbb{Z} (\subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i])$. In particular,
$$ (a+b i)+J=(a+b i)-(a-2 a i)+J=(b+2 a) i+J, $$
so every coset has a representative of the form $b i$ with $b \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Since $5=(1+2 i)(1-2 i)$ is a multiple of $1-2 i$, we have $5 \in J$ and thus $5 i \in J$. Therefore, we can represent every coset of the form $b i+J$ with $b \in{0, \ldots, 4}$
Therefore,
$$
R / J=\{0+J, i+J, 2 i+J, 3 i+J, 4 i+J\}, \quad \text { and thus } \quad|R / J| \leq 5,
$$
with equality if and only if all 5 cosets are distinct. If $b i+J=b^{\prime} i+J$ with $0 \leq b<b^{\prime} \leq 4$, then $\left(b^{\prime}-b\right) i \in J$, where $b^{\prime}-b \in{1,2,3,4}$. However, this is not possible, because the norm of an element from $J$ is divisible by the norm of the generator, i.e., for all $z \in J$, $5=\left.(1-2 i)(1+2 i)|z \bar{z}=| z\right|^2$.
I have an old math exam question with the solution included, but there are certain steps of the solution I don't understand.
Questions:

So it is known that every prime element is irreducible. So for the generator of $J=(1-2 i) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i] .$ you can check if it's a prime element by calculating the norm of the element, which is $5$. Can you check irreducibility for any complex number this way in any given ring?
How does the following come about?: $$ (a+b i)+J=(a+b i)-(a-2 a i)+J=(b+2 a) i+J $$ At the beginning, any coset is generally symbolized by $(a+bi)+J$. We had previously defined that $a(1-2i)$ is any element from $J$. Therefore, I thought that in the equation, $J$ would be replaced by $a(1-2i)$, but instead, it was subtracted additionally, and $J$ is still added. Why is that the case? And why does $a(1-2i)$ specifically need to be subtracted, can it be added instead?
Afterwards the conclusion was drawn that every coset can be represented with $b i+J$? Why is only the prefactor of the imaginary part $b$ used to represent the cosets and not also the real part $2a$? Why can every coset be represented with $bi+J$?
Since $5=(1+2 i)(1-2 i)$ is a multiple of $1-2 i$, we have $5 \in J$ and thus $5 i \in J$. Why can $5$ be $b$ even tho it's the norm of the generator and not the prefactor of the imaginary part? It follows that $b$ can only take values from $0$ to $4$. Why can it only take these values?
In the last step to check if cosets are distinct the solution proves that the difference of $\left(b^{\prime}-b\right) i \in J$ is such that $b^{\prime}-b \in{1,2,3,4}$. So it means that all the cosets are distinct because this would lead to a contradiction because the norm of all the elements in $J$ must be divisible by the norm of the generator. How can we infer the that norm of any given element in $J$ is divisible by $5$ through the above statement?

Some definitions:

Theorem 1: Let $R$ be a domain (a commutative ring with no zero divisors) that is a principal ideal ring, and let $a \in R$ with $a \neq 0$. Then, $(a)$ is a maximal ideal of $R$ if and only if $a$ is irreducible.
Corollary 1: Let $R$ be an integral domain (a commutative ring with no zero divisors) that is a principal ideal ring, and let $a \in R$. Then, $R/(a)$ is a field if and only if $a$ is irreducible in $R$.
Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$. Then, the set of right cosets $G / N={N g \mid g \in G}$ together with the operation
$$
\left(N g_1\right) \cdot\left(N g_2\right):=N\left(g_1 g_2\right)
$$
forms a group. This group is called the quotient group or factor group of $G$ modulo $N$.

Thanks in advance!

Tangentially, the fastest way to compute this quotient is to observe that $$\mathbb{Z}\left[i\right]/\left(1-2i\right)\ \simeq\ \mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]/\left(x^{2}+1,2x-1\right)\ \simeq\ \mathbb{Z}\left[x\right]/\left(x-3,5\right)\ \simeq\ \mathbb{F}_{5}\text{.}$$ (No special facts about PIDs or Dedekind domains required.)

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$
The short answer is that the methods used in this problem do not generalize to arbitrary rings of integers of number fields - i.e., other integral subrings of $\C$ which share many of the same properties.
Checking irreducibility in $\Z[i]$ cannot always be reduced to checking whether the norm is prime. For instance, $3$ is prime in $\Z[i]$, although its norm is not. However, using the norm is a very powerful tool to narrow down the possible factors of a number. For instance, the only possible divisors of $3$ must have norm $1, 3, $ or $9$, and it is easy to check by hand there are no elements of norm $3$, and every element of norm $1$ is a unit. In more general rings of integers, such as $\Z[\sqrt{-5}]$, irreducibility and primality do not coincide because the ring fails to be a unique factorization domain. For instance,
$$6 = 2\cdot 3 = (1 + \sqrt{-5})(1 - \sqrt{-5})$$
and $2, 3, 1+\sqrt{-5}, 1- \sqrt{-5}$ are all irreducible in $\Z[\sqrt{-5}]$.
When determining $|R/J|$, there is care needed when writing explicit representatives of the cosets $R/J$. There are many ways of writing the representatives and proving that these in fact cover all the cosets of $R/J$: the solution you have posted is just one such method.

Nevertheless, since norm is multiplicative, prime norm implies irreducibility.

In fact, prime norm implies even primality because a finite ring with a prime number of elements is a field.


If with "any given ring" you mean a subset of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then yes. For $\alpha\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ with $N(\alpha)$ prime, assume $\alpha = \beta\gamma$. Then $N(\alpha) = N(\beta\gamma) = N(\beta)N(\gamma)$, and since this is prime, one of the norms has to be 1, which means one of the elements is a unit. Therefore $\alpha$ is irreducible.
This is seen more easily using bar notation, because $(a+bi) + J = \overline{a+bi}$ in R/J. It follows that $\overline{a+bi} = \overline{a+bi} - \overline{0} = \overline{a+bi} - \overline{a-2ai} = \overline{(b+2a)i}$. This works, because as the answer shows, $a-2ai$ is an element of $J$ and therefore equivalent to $\overline{0}$.
Notice that $(b+2a)i$ is just an integer multiplied by $i$, and therefore of the form $ci$, $c\in\mathbb{Z}$. Your question is caused by unclear notation from the answer, because the b in the answer is not the same b that was used in the previous calculation.
As previously seen, any coset can be represented by $bi$. Because $\overline{5i} = \overline{0}$, and $b$ can be written as $5q + r$ for $q,r\in\mathbb{Z}$ with $0 \leq r < 5$, it follows that $\overline{bi} = \overline{(5q+r)i} = \overline{5qi} + \overline{ri} = \overline{ri}$.
for $\alpha\in J$, $\alpha$ can be written as $\beta (1-2i)$. it follows that $N(\alpha) = N(\beta)N(1-2i) = 5N(\beta)$, and therefore $N(\alpha)$ is a multiple of 5.

